# execute Python script with Cron

Tags: python, cron, raspberry-pi

I'm just getting to grips with Python and Cron (and Raspberry Pi).

I've written a script that sends me an email that I plan to have send me stats about my website on a daily basis. The script works fine, if I load it up in Idle and hit F5, I get an email.

I've tried to get this to work in Cron, I've tried using command line and with the Gnome program but it doesn't do anything - I think I might have something wrong with the Cron command...

```
30 12 * * * /home/pi/Python/Email.py
```

should this work or have I missed something?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could try

```
30 12 * * * python /home/pi/Python/Email.py
```

or change permission of your file:

```
chmod +x /home/pi/Python/Email.py
```